# SQL code to set a specific date as compared to "today's" date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

In the first column (Report_Date) of this query the date is being constructed and is today's day, and is used in the following lines to select is the following columns.  I'd like to use a specific day in the query.

I'd like help to write the format to replace column 1 (Report_Date) with a different date to create aging, like June 1st - 2021-06-01.

```
SELECT
  convert(datetime,convert(char,datepart(mm,getdate()))+'/'+convert(char,datepart(dd,getdate()))+'/'+convert(char,datepart(yyyy,getdate())))Report_Date,


  sum(case
when datediff(dd, (convert(datetime,convert(char,B.Original_Bill_Date,101))), getdate()) 
Between 0 and 30 then B.CurrentBalance else 0
end) '0-30',

  sum(case
when datediff(dd, (convert(datetime,convert(char,B.Original_Bill_Date,101))), getdate()) 
Between 31 and 60 then B.CurrentBalance else 0
end) '31-60',

  sum(case
when datediff(dd, (convert(datetime,convert(char,B.Original_Bill_Date,101))), getdate()) 
Between 61 and 90 then B.CurrentBalance else 0
end) '61-90',

  sum(case
when datediff(dd, (convert(datetime,convert(char,B.Original_Bill_Date,101))), getdate()) 
Between 91 and 120 then B.CurrentBalance else 0
end) '91-120',


  B.Primary_Payer_Code,
  B.Secondary_Payer_Code,
  B.CurrentResponsibility_desc,
  Case When G.PAYER_GROUP IS NOT NULL Then G.PAYER_GROUP
    Else Case When B.Primary_Payer_Code = 'PP' Then 'SELF PAY' Else 
    F.Description End End

FROM
  Date D with (nolock)
  JOIN TEL_BILLED_LINE_ITEM_ODS B with (nolock) ON ( convert(datetime,convert(char,B.Original_Bill_Date,101)) = D.DATE)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TBLPAYER_ODS P with (nolock) ON B.Primary_Payer_Code=P.Code
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TBLFINANCIALCLASS_ODS F with (nolock) ON F.tblfinancialclassid = P.FinancialClassID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PAYER_GROUP G ON G.PAYER_CODE = P.CODE
  
WHERE
      ( B.CurrentBalance !=  0)
    AND B.BadDebtFlagYN=0 
   
    AND B.Primary_Payer_Code !='CL'  -- exclude CLIENT 07/01/2010 jdw
  
 
GROUP BY
  B.Primary_Payer_Code,
  B.Secondary_Payer_Code,
  B.CurrentResponsibility_desc,
   Case When G.PAYER_GROUP IS NOT NULL Then G.PAYER_GROUP
    Else Case When B.Primary_Payer_Code = 'PP' Then 'SELF PAY' Else 
    F.Description End End
```

Comment: The above code is sensitive to session settings like `set dateformat dmy`, have you considered using [`datefromparts()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql) to construct dates instead?

Comment: I've not tried that I'll do that now, thx.